# Is this the best way of getting tomorrow 09:00?

Tags: datetime, go, time

I want to get a datetime object for tomorrow morning 09:00 in Go. My current take is this:

```
now := time.Now()
tomorrowMorning := time.Date(now.Year(), now.Month(), now.Day(), 9, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC).AddDate(0, 0, 1))
```

It seems oddly verbose though. Isn't there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: Do you want  that in UTC really?

Answer (score 5):

Simplify by adding 1 to the day directly.

```
now := time.Now()
tomorrowMorning := time.Date(now.Year(), now.Month(), now.Day() + 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1RAkdsOyoLo).

The `time.Date` function normalizes the day.